# How to correctly use UIResponder.pressesBegan to detect multi-key input

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am working on an iOS 13+ project which includes a view that can be used as calculator. The number block used to input numbers and operators (+ - * / ...) is build using simple `UIButtons`. The current value is shown in a `UILabel`.

Now I would like to extend the existing code to also accept input from connected hardware keyboards. I have extended `UILabel` to handle the `UIResponder` method `pressesBegan:withEvent`:

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }

    switch key.keyCode {
    case .keyboard1:
    case .keypad1:
        insertNumber(1)
    case .keyboard2:
    case .keypad2:
        insertNumber(2)

    ...        

    case .keypadPlus:
        add()

    ...

    default:
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }
}
```

This works fine when using a keyboard with a numberblock. However, I would like to also support keyboard without a numberblock. In this case the `*` sign for example can only be entered using two keys `Shift +` (on a Keyboard with German layout).

However, when typing `Shift +`the `presses:with:` method is called twice. Once for the `Shift` key and once for the `+` key. I am not sure why presses is `Set` when each keystroke is handled separately.

**So, how to detect multi key combinations?**

Answer (score 1):

You can check **key.modifierFlags** property.
The type is:

```swift
public struct UIKeyModifierFlags : OptionSet
```

The flag you need is **.shift**.
You can compare modifierFlags to single value or array literal:

```swift
if key.modifierFlags == .shift {
 // position of these two flags doesn't matter
}
```

NOTE#1:

You should find out which keycode(UIKeyboardHIDUsage) mapped to German keyboard "+", I find it from some source to be **.keyboardCloseBracket**
(48, or 0x30). If wrong, tell me and I will correct it.
Also, you can check real characters send from **key.characters** (as String type)

Some prototype code here:

```swift
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }
    switch key.keyCode {
    ... (many keyCode cases omitted)
    case .keyboardCloseBracket: // See NOTE#1
        if key.modifierFlags == .shift {
            // yout want "shift + " as "*"
        } else {
            // not the state for plus you want, pass it
            super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
        }
    ... 
    default:
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }
}
```

NOTE#2:

No need to tell between left-shift and right-shift for **.modifierFlags** --
They are different only in **.keyCode**