# Detect shift + return key when UITextView is the responder

Tags: swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate, uikeycommand

I want to detect if the user presses either just **"return"** key or **"shift+return"** key on the external keyboard to perform two different actions when the UITextView is the responder.

It works when UITextView is not responding by using UIKeyCommands

```
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        return [
            UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(taskOne)),
            UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: .shift, action: #selector(taskTwo)),
        ]
}
```

But when UITextView is being edited, it just adds a new line and doesn't detect these UIKeyCommands.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override press began function

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event:  UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }
    
    switch key.keyCode {
    case .keyboardReturn:
        if key.modifierFlags == .shift {
            taskTwo()
        } else {
            // not the state for plus you want, pass it
            taskOne()
        }
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
        break
    default:
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }
}
```

and override func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool

for UITextViewDelegate

[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665361/how-to-correctly-use-uiresponder-pressesbegan-to-detect-multi-key-input)

Comment: Thank you, that worked exactly as I wanted.